# What to do with slow soap request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller has a slow soap-request (receive the data from third party service). So the page renders only after the request ends.

I would like to first renders page. The data from the query I can wait.

What better to do in this case?
sidekiq, ajax?

Comment: I think ajax + spinner is enough if soap request takes less than 30sec

Answer (score 0):

my recommendation, is using active job that you can read more from [rails guide activejob](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) and adding to the queue then for the worker you can choose between delayjob, resque, and sidekiq, I personally choose resque because it's has web interface to monitor the worker that execute the queue and easy to setup with redis and systemd configuration, here is [some info about pro and cons between those three](https://imvishaltyagi444.wordpress.com/2016/07/11/delayed-job-vs-resque-vs-sidekiq/)

and may be this [railscast episode 366](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq) can help you how you can combine with your project